# integrate custom marketplace catalog eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I created a custom marketplace catalog and I would like to integrate it in Eclipse. I've been using this [marketplace project](http://sourceforge.net/p/marketplace-cat/home/Home/) , but I can not manage to show it.
   I need more ideas how to do this . Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I needed:

[Solution Provider Marketplace Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EPP/MPC/Solution_Provider_Testing_Guide)